# Is there only a Date type like TimeSpan instead of DateTime?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

In my application I have a `Movie` type and `User` type where any `User` can specify when they saw a particular movie in their logs along with ratings, etc, but I am only interested in the day not the time, so was wondering if there is only a `Date` type that stores only the day and nothing else, i.e. no `Time`.

Comment: Uless you writing strictly for India consder impact of timezones - even EST & PST give you 2 hours when "Date" is not the same...

Comment: Thanks, I am not sure what you mean though. If I only store the day, would I have difference in days except for India?

Comment: India have one single time zone - so everyone's day is the same; US on other hand have 3 time zones - so if person in New-York did something Oct 15, 1:00AM does it mean Oct 14 or Oct 15 for Califirnia folks?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov (The 'States has four timezones, by the way: Pacific, Mountain, Central, and Eastern) :)

Comment: Thanks (definitly not smarter than fifth grader: 8-5 = 3 hence 3 time zones :))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is not. Closest thing, if you *must* ensure there's no time data attached to your `DateTime` object, is to use the [`DateTime.Date` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date.aspx), whose return value is another `DateTime`, but with the time value set to 00:00:00 (midnight).

And of course, when displaying the date, you can control its [formatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx) as you like.

[In particular, the Short Date specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx#ShortDate):

```
var dateValue = new DateTime(2011, 10, 14);
dateValue.ToString("d");
```

Will output `10/14/2011` in the Invariant culture.

Answer (score 3):

You typically use a `DateTime` with the time set to midnight. You can turn any time stamp into a date using the `DateTime.Date` property.

If you need a more compact representation you could calculate an integer that represents the date as number of days since a certain day, but I'd only do this if it's really necessary.

But `DateTime` is a bit ugly for local times(It's OK for UTC times), so you could consider working with `DateTimeOffset` or alternatively use a third party library.

Answer (score 2):

No, there isn't. You *can* use `DateTime`, but I don't recommend it. It's fundamentally the wrong type for the job, and it has some [very odd characteristics](http://noda-time.blogspot.com/2011/08/what-wrong-with-datetime-anyway.html).

I'm busy working on [Noda Time](http://noda-time.googlecode.com), an alternative date and time library for .NET based on the calculation engine of [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) but with a mostly-from-scratch API. It's not fully production ready yet, but it's getting there - and I'd be interested in giving as much assistance as necessary to early adopters...

Of course, we support `LocalDate` :) (It doesn't just store the date - it also stores the calendar system it's using, so that if you're not using the common Gregorian calendar, you can still perform operations in your natural system, but that's a different matter.)

Comment: Thanks Jon, so your Noda Time supports only Date? Also why would you not recommend using `DateTime`?

Comment: @JoanVenge: Yes, there's a `LocalDate` type. See the [concepts documentation](http://noda-time.googlecode.com/hg/docs/userguide/concepts.html) for more details. And I've edited a link into my answer to explain some of what I dislike about `DateTime`.

Comment: `DateTime` is a big ugly for local times. Local times are complicated, and `DateTime` is a bit too simplistic to model that complexity. I have no problem with `DateTime` and UTC times(Which in my use-cases are much more common anyways).

Comment: @CodeInChaos: You don't mind the fact that `DateTime` doesn't represent a UTC time, or at least *might* not? Rather than me rant in the comments here, I'll let you read the link in the first paragraph. There are good reasons to dislike `DateTime`, IMO. Even if *you* get it right, how confident are you that all your coworkers will always do the right thing with `DateTime`?

Comment: Most of my methods dealing with `DateTimes` have a `Contract.Requires(mydata.Kind=DateTimeKind.Utc)` that ensure it's getting UTC times. Slightly ugly, I admit, but for most projects I prefer that over adding a third party library.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: Ah, that's just because you haven't experienced the joys of Noda Time, with multiple types each expressing a distinct concept :)

Comment: That's mainly because almost all my uses are one concept: Identifying a certain point in the recent past and possibly conversion to the users local time zone on output. If I need anything more complicated than that I'll look into Noda.

Comment: @Jon: Thanks, I wish they added your stuff to .NET as I heard you were involved with this kind of date-time stuff before. Also you said your `LocalDate` doesn't have any connection to a calender system. In that case, what are the advantages, like I am not sure what this does? Without this info, can you still operate on the dates easily when subtracting them or getting how many days in between two `LocalDate` values?

Comment: @JoanVenge: No, it *does* know what calendar system it's in. So you can add a month (for example) and it'll add it in the right calendar system. And yes, you can easily get the days between two dates.

Comment: @Jon: Thanks, I will probably use yours, my app is very early now, but it's not very huge. But since you said it's not fully production yet, you still have to add a lot of other stuff? I assume it will take a lot of spare time for you finish it, right?

Comment: One thing I would like to see in a time-handling library is a data type which can specify which of (absolute-time, time-zone, local-time) should be regarded as 'most certain' or 'least certain', to allow for data cleanup in cases where some attribute of some timestamps may be erroneous.  Changing one of those three properties on a time stamp would cause a corresponding change the less-certain of the remaining two.  Not all data problems could be resolved (some are simply unsolvable) but it would seem that in many real-world cases, one may know one of the items more certainly than the others.

Comment: @JoanVenge: There's not a *great* deal more to do, but yes, it's taking a fair amount of my time :)

Comment: @supercat: If you'd fancy elaborating on that theme on the Noda Time mailing list, I'd be interested to hear more about it.

Answer (score 1):

Use the DateTime constructor that takes year, month and day:

```
public DateTime(
      int year,
      int month,
      int day
  )
```

E.g.

```
DateTime usersDate = new DateTime(2011, 10, 14);
```

Note that this still uses the same type, but with a zero time (midnight).

Answer (score 0):

In the BCL, no.  But you can use the various `ToString` overrides to display (return a string) that contains just a date and ignores the time portion.

Answer (score 0):

No. But you could create one, of you need it (based on DateTime)

Answer (score 0):

Not as far as I'm aware, but you can always just refer to the `Date` portion of the `DateTime` object.

Like this: `DateTime myDate = DateTime.Now.Date;`

Answer (score 0):

This is what [DateTime.Date](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date.aspx) is for.  It's still a DateTime, but it zeroes the time for you.  Just use this consistently and you'll get what you want.